# ios Reloading TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am editing the Email on the second viewController. The Label.text(in ViewController) does change if i modify the email address in the second view(tableViewBudget), but the table view Cell does not change. It always shows the first value of savedEmail.text. How can I modify my code so that tableView cell will change when i change the string in the other table View? Thank You!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController:UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var savedEmail: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
     }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func exitToHere ( sender: UIStoryboardSegue){
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
        cell.textLabel?.text = savedEmail.text
        return cell
    }
}
```

**Second View Controller**

```
import UIKit

 class TableviewBudget: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }   
    @IBAction func updateEmail(_ sender: Any) {
        (presentingViewController as! ViewController).savedEmail.text =
            self.emailField.text
    }

    @IBAction func hideKeyboard(_ sender: Any) {
        self.emailField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.emailField.text = (presentingViewController as! ViewController).savedEmail.text

        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

}
```

Comment: Try calling reloadData() on the table inside the updateEmail method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use delegates to send a callback to the first `UIViewController`, in your case class `ViewController` as soon as user is done editing the text.

In your class `TableViewBudget` change it to like so, this will create a delegate to pass data to a previous view controller

**For Swift 3**

```
protocol delegateVC{

    func updateEmail(email : String)
}

class TableviewBudget: UIViewController{
    //add this inside this class
    var delegate : delegateVC?
    ...
}
```

Now change your function to

```
@IBAction func updateEmail(_ sender: Any) {
    self.delegate?.updateEmail(email: self.emailField.text)
}
```

Now in your class `ViewController` add-

```
class ViewController:UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate, delegateVC{

     func updateEmail(email : String){
         //update label here inside your first VC by getting the cell, using the indexPath of the cell that contains the E-mail
         //also update your modal here to contain the next email otherwise if cellForRow gets called again, the e-mail field will get reset
         cell.textLabel?.text = email
     }
}
```

Also remember to set this delegate in your `prepareForSegue` while you push `TableViewBudget` from `ViewController`, something like

```
let tableViewBudget = TableViewBudget()
tableViewBudget.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 0):

in ViewController:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    tableView.reload()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to call

```
 tableView.reloadData()
```

or

```
 tableView.beginUpdates()
 tableView.reloadRows(at: [yourIndexPath], with: .fade)
 tableView.endUpdates()
```

Second version is better when you have to much rows but you want to reload only one or few of them